# Cambiar imagen en miniatura de mi web (wordpress.org) para facebook o linkedin

Tags: html, wordpress, web

Buenas a todos, al linkear la url de mi web (http://www.start2develop.com) en facebook o linkedin me aparece una imagen en blanco con el titulo y poco más. Lo que quiero es que aparezca una imagen predefinida por mi. 
Facebook me da un poco igual pero si me interesa mucho el en linkedin. Se que hay que añadir alguna etiqueta meta tipo :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.start2develop.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Start2DevelopLogo.jpg"/>
```

He probado en el header.php content.php pero nada ¿En que archivo de mi web debería añadirlo?(Uso wordpress.org). 
llevo toda la tarde intentando cosas y seguro que al final es una tontería, un saludo y gracias de antemano por la ayuda!.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún tema de terceros instalado en tu WP o sólo los temas propios de WP?

Comment: Viendo que tienes el plugin de Yoast, para no duplicar contenido modificando tu archivo `functions.php`, la mejor opción sería a mi juicio que uses dicho plugin para configurar los atributos Open Graph. [La página del plugin explica aquí](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/getting-open-graph-for-your-articles/) la forma de hacerlo. Linkedin no requiere configuraciones especiales, lo cual significa que las de FB y/o Twitter te servirían. Ten en cuenta que a veces la antigua imagen se queda en memoria y que debes ir a la página debug de FB y hacer scrap para resetear al nuevo valor de la imagen.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas , utilizo el tema OneTone de Magee, por lo que veo actualmente para realizar el tema de visualizaciones en twitter y facebook pide ser premium en Yoast :(

Comment: NMV creo que con AIO Seo me deja, pruebo y confirmo.

Comment: Yo te podría responder con una función para personalizar los Open Graph, pero deberías informarte sobre la forma concreta en que habría que incluir dicha función. No sé si ese tema se usa basado en algún framework como Thesis o Génesis (en cuyo caso habría que incluir la función en un archivo llamado `custom.php`) o si ese tema en concreto trabaja directamente con `functions.php`

Comment: Bueno he conseguido hacerlo gracias al plugin de AIO Seo, muy facil, lo único ajustar el tamaño adecuado poco más, el problema que sigue es en linkedin, no aparece imagen al añadir el link :/

Comment: Raul, vas a necesitar resetear el caché de Linkedin ya que, como las otras redes sociales, guarda la imagen anterior y al parecer no tiene una herramienta de debug. En algunos sitios explican que para hacerlo, puedes agregar un query string a la url original y luego cambiarlo. [Más detalles aquí](https://woorkup.com/linkedin-cache/)

Comment: Perfecto , simplemente añadiendo /?1 a la Url en Linkedin se actualiza , muchísimas gracias.